# MQQueue Properties (C# API to Websphere MQ)

Tags: c#-4.0, ibm-mq

I found this code to enumerate a list of queues for a QueueManager. 
It works, but I see a lot of System Queues, and even channel names in the list it provides. Is there some property I can test to see if it is a "normal" user-defined queue? 
ObjectType, QueueType, Usage seemed to always give same values for every queue-name.

```
            // GET QueueNames - this worked on 07/19/2012 - but returned a lot of system queue, and unclear how to separate user queues from system queues. 
            PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent(mqQMgr);

            // Build the query request.
            PCFMessage requestMessage = new PCFMessage(CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_NAMES);
            requestMessage.AddParameter(MQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, "*");

            // Send the request and retrieve the response.
            PCFMessage[] responses = agent.Send(requestMessage);

            // Retrieve the values requested from the response.
            string[] queueNames = responses[0].GetStringListParameterValue(CMQCFC.MQCACF_Q_NAMES);
            //string[] objType = responses[0].GetStringListParameterValue(CMQCFC.MQIACF_OBJECT_TYPE);

            int loopCounter = 0;
            foreach (string queueName in queueNames)
            {
                loopCounter++;
                Console.WriteLine("QueueName=" + queueName);
                try
                {
                    mqQueue = mqQMgr.AccessQueue(
                             queueName,
                             MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT                   // open queue for output
                             + MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE              // inquire required to get CurrentDepth 
                             + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);   // but not if MQM stopping


                    Console.WriteLine("QueueName=" + queueName +
                                      " CurrentDepth=" + mqQueue.CurrentDepth +
                                      " MaxDepth=" + mqQueue.MaximumDepth + 
                                      " QueueType=" + mqQueue.QueueType +
                                      " Usage=" + mqQueue.Usage
                                      );
                }
                catch (MQException mex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(mex.Message);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me your sample code lists only queues, no other objects but yes it lists all queues. You can add another filter `requestMessage.AddParameter(MQC.MQIA_Q_TYPE, MQC.MQQT_MODEL);` to list only model queues. Other values available for `MQC.MQIA_Q_TYPE` are `MQC.MQQT_LOCAL`, `MQQT_ALIAS`, `MQQT_CLUSTER` and `MQC.MQQT_REMOTE`.

All system or predefined queue names begin with `SYSTEM`. So you could probably use this string filter out predefined queues after listing. Also if you look at a queue definition, there is DEFTYPE attribute, system defined queues have value of `PREDEFINED`. But I could not add a third parameter to filter queue names by DEFTYPE. I got 3014 reason code.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

As Shashi noted, you will only see queue names from that PCF command.

If you only queue names that begin with PAYROLL then change:

```
requestMessage.AddParameter(MQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, "*");
```

to

```
requestMessage.AddParameter(MQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, "PAYROLL.*");
```

Or add an if statement to exclude the queue names you do not want to see:

```
if (!(queueName.startsWith("SYSTEM.")))
{
   // do something
}
```